# Can I reuse a URL from a deleted project?

Tags: firebase, url

Someone deleted my firebase apps and websites.

Can I get the URLs with another project if it is not in use anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project was deleted within the past 30 days, the owner may be able to [restore it from the Google Cloud console](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787#zippy=%2Crestore-a-project).

Once a project is permanently deleted, its project name (and from that, its database URL, and web URL) can never be reclaimed or restored.

Comment: But what if I want to use the URL for another project?

Comment: You can't. As said: once deleted, the URL can't be used for any new project.

Comment: But I owned the last project.